# Confused about expressing a distribution as a sum of random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding about expressing a distribution as a sum of random variables.

Given $X \sim Hypergeometric(N, k, n)$, $X$ can be written as $X$ = $X_1$ + ... + $X_n$, where $X_i \sim Bernoulli(k/N)$ and dependent on each other.

Suppose $X \sim Hypergeometric(N=4, k=2, n=4)$, then $X$ = $X_1$ + $X_2$ + $X_3$ + $X_4$, where $X_i \sim Bernoulli(0.5)$.

Could we not have $X_1 = 0$, $X_2 = 0$, $X_3 = 0$, $X_4 = 0$, and thus $X = 0$ which is impossible? I understand that the $X_i$ are dependent on each other but we're using their unconditional forms in our equation for $X$. What mistake have I made here?

Comment: No. If without replacement $n=4$ balls are drawn from $N=4$ balls  among which $k=2$ are red then we cannot have $X_i=0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. This because it is for sure that we will draw $2$ red balls (not zero). So for two distinct indices $i,j$ we will have $X_i=1=X_j$.

Comment: The important point is that the $X_i$ are dependent as you said. Here, the dependence will be such that at no point all four of the $X_i$ can be zero. For clarity, forget for a moment about the hypergeometric distribution and consider a Bernoulli variable $X_1\sim Bernoulli(0.5)$. Set $X_2 = X_1$ and $X_3 =X_4 := 1-X_1$. Then, $X = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4$ is the sum of four $Bernoulli(0.5)$ random variables (as $1-X_1$ is also $Bernoulli(0.5)$!). However, $X = X_1 + X_1 + (1-X_1) + (1-X_1) = 2$ is constant!!

Comment: @MushuNrek Thank you, that makes a lot of sense.